# Import de variables desde un archivo a otro con el FROM

Tags: python, python-import

La intención es acceder desde un archivo (llamado, digamos, "**`index.py`**") a las variables definidas en otro (por ejemplo, "**`config.py`**").
Es decir, importar, a un archivo, las variables del otro.

Vale, estos son los contenidos de los archivos:

[**`config.py`**]

```
# encoding: utf-8

_root_tit = 'Título de la Aplicación'
_root_w = 1025
_root_h = 600
_root_bg = 'black'
_db_data_conn = {'db_name': 'db_miBase', 'password': 'xxxx', 'charset': 'utf8', 'use_unicode': True, 'user': 'usu_miBase'}
```

[**`index.py`**]

```
# encoding: utf-8

# Recuperando ENTORNO
#-----------------------------------------
from config import *

# Recogiendo datos
#-----------------------------------------
print('o> _root_tit: {}'.format(_root_tit))
print('o> _root_w: {}'.format(_root_w))
print('o> _root_h: {}'.format(_root_h))
print('o> _root_bg: {}'.format(_root_bg))
print('o> _db_data_conn: {}'.format(_db_data_conn))
```

En principio, así, debería funcionar ya que, del archivo "**`config.py`**" (`from config`) importo todo su contenido (`import *`). En este caso, todas sus variables. ¿No es así?
Y, además, según había aprendido (a no ser que me equivoque), con esta forma de importar, se puede llamar al nombre de la variable directamente, por ejemplo, `_root_tit`, sin pasar por tener que preceder el nombre de la variable por el del archivo que se importa, es decir `config._root_tit`.
¿O es que me equivoco?

Bueno, pues al ejecutar "**`index.py`**" en la terminal, me sale el ERROR de que las variables no están definidas. Ya, al no encontrar la definición de la primera variable llamada con el `print()` desde el "**`index.py`**", se para.

"**`Mensaje de Error`**"

```
NameError: name '_root_tit' is not defined
```

En cambio, si que funciona, si sustituyo la forma de importar de esto:

```
from config import *
```

a esto:

```
import config as cfg
```

Claro, luego, a la hora de llamar a cada variable importada, tengo que poner:

```
cfg.variable_que_sea
```

Entonces, la pregunta es:
¿Por qué se llega a las variables a importar con `import config as cfg` y no con `from config import *`? ¿Faltaría algo para poder llegar a través de `from config import *`?

Espero vuestras respuestas aclaratorias. Gracias. Saludos.

NOTA EXTRA: funcionando en Ubuntu 16.04 con Python 2.7 (pero, supongo, que esto también se podrá aplicar a las versiones 3.x).

Comment: Por cierto (no relacionado con lo preguntado), ¿no hay un error en la última línea de `config.py`? Creo que en lugar del `=` de la asignación has puesto `:`.

Comment: Si, es verdad, me confundí al pasar el código. Puse `_db_data_conn: {...` y es `_db_data_conn = {...` Lo corrijo ahora mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En general se desaconseja el uso de `from modulo import *`, porque no sabes a priori si lo que vas a importar entrará en conflicto con otras cosas que hayas importado del mismo modo (pues dos módulos diferentes podrían declarar clases, funciones o variables con igual nombre).

Lo que se recomienda es ser más explícito con lo que quieres importar, por ejemplo así:

```
from config import (_root_tit, _root_w,
                    _root_h, _root_bg)
```

La versión anterior también te ahorra tener que usar el nombre del módulo delante de cada identificador, pero al ser explícito con qué importas y qué no, evitas los posibles conflictos de un `from modulo import *`.

---

Pero respondiendo a tu pregunta de por qué el `from config import *` no funcionó, la razón es que la sintaxis `*` en un `import` no importa todos los identificadores definidos en el módulo, sino sólo aquellos que estén "declarados" para ello. La declaración consiste en meterlos todos en un array llamado `__all__`.

Así pues, tu módulo `config.py` debería terminar con una línea como esta:

```
__all__ = [ '_root_tit', '_root_w', '_root_h', '_root_bg', '_db_data_conn' ]
```

Los identificadores que metas en esa lista serán los que se importarán al usar la expresión `from config import *`. (Los no incluidos en esa lista aún pueden ser importados explícitamente, como en `from config import foo`)

Comment: Muy bien. He probado la solución del `__all__` pero, a mí, al menos, me funciona si cada nombre de variable a incluir en esa lista es puesto entre comillas, es decir, `__all__ = [ '_root_tit', '_root_w', '_root_h', '_root_bg', '_db_data_conn' ]`. Luego, parece que da igual que sea al principio o al final del archivo `config.py`. Lo he probado, como sugerías como última línea, y bien. Y he probado poniéndolo justo antes de las declaraciones de las variables del `config.py` y también funciona.

Comment: No obstante, entonces, ¿cuál sería la solución más recomendable?: ¿la de usar en el `index.py` el `from config import variable_1, variable_2, ...`? ¿o la poner en el `index.py` el `from config import *` y en el `config.py` incluir el `__all__ = [ 'variable_1', 'variable_2', ... ]`?

Comment: tienes razon, olvide las comillas. He actualizado la respuesta

Comment: La primera opción es la que recomienda el zen de python: "Explícito es mejor que implícito". Por cierto, si quieres leer el zen, haz `import this` ;-)

Comment: Vale, entendido que la primera es más Zen :). Pero claro, yo he puesto un ejemplo con 5 variables que importo. Pero, en verdad, en mi archivo son unas 20, entonces, me que da un churro algo grande. Y, en este caso, son 20 pero en otros casos o cuando importas un módulo de terceros son más aún, por eso, no parece una solución muy elegante al final y se me parece más limpia al ojo la del `__all__`. Pero bueno, todo sea por el Zen ... Por cierto, no he pillado del todo tu comentario de que para leer el zen, ponga `import this` ¿Quieres decir que lo ponga en un nuevo archivo y ejecute o qué? :)

Comment: @zacktagnan Sí, o en un intérprete interactivo :). En cuanto a este caso particular, tratándose de un fichero de configuración, y si los nombres de las variables no se prestan a colisiones con otras, podría admitirse el uso de `*`, pero no sé, yo sigo prefiriendo un `import config as c`, por ejemplo, y luego `c.variable`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77599/discussion-between-zacktagnan-and-abulafia).

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tienes un archivo de configuración lalado config.py en un directorio llamado ./base/utilidades

```
'''
archivo de configuración
'''
URL="https://servidor.cut/index.php"
USER="usuario"
PASS="passa"
```

Supongamos que tu archivo python principal está en el directorio ./base
Sólo tienes que hacer:

```
'''
programa principal
'''
import utilidades.config as conf
print("url:", conf.URL)
```