# Como puedo leer el valor de las variables de otro scrip? python get

Tags: python, post, get

> Buenas yo tengo 2 script, 1 que tiene variables con valores y el otro
> que quiere leer los valores del 1 script, como hago eso con python?

```
nombre= "mauricio"
apellido = "sanchez"
Edad = 19
        
if (nombre == "mauricio"):
    #Reasignar nuevos nombres
    nombre = "pablo"
    apellido  = "ramirez"
    Edad  = 25
```

> Desde otro script, como hago para leer los datos que estan dentro del
> if?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Import de variables desde un archivo a otro con el FROM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164861/import-de-variables-desde-un-archivo-a-otro-con-el-from)

Comment: no, desde el archivo 2 intenté llamar solo 1 variable apellido haciendo print(apellido)  pero no me trae los valores

Comment: dandole importar, el segundo script comienza a hacer lo mismo que el script 1 es como si el script 2 se transformara en el script 1 y yo quiero que el script 2 sea independiente y haga cosas aparte, solo que lea los valores de las variables dentro del if y después si ejecute unas operaciones si me explico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas tener un archivo principal, comúnmente un 'main.py', donde se ejecutara toda tu código, ahí tienes que importar tu código, supongamos que el archivo desde donde importas tus variables se llama 'variables.py', entonces tu código en main.py debería ser algo así:

```
from variables import nombre

print(nombre)
```

lo anterior solo llamara la variable 'nombre', para llamar todo debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import variables

name = variables.name
last_name = variables.apellido
age = variables.Edad
```

pero esto no ejecutara el if así que te pasara los valores que defines primero

Comment: y suponiendo que quiero tomar los datos que estan dentro de un ciclo while? como hago? ejemplo 
main.py
import time

conteo = 0

for i in range(0,1000,1):
    conteo = conteo + 1
    time.sleep(5)

variables.py

from main import conteo

while True:
    print(conteo)

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer pero si quieres escribir código mas complejo en archivos a parte deberías crear funciones con entradas y retorno de un valor.

Comment: Gracias, por la respuesta si me ayudo lo del from variable import tales