# Uso correcto de __INIT__ y creación de objetos

Tags: python

Escribo porque estoy cometiendo un error en el manejo de:

1. `__init__`
2. La creación del objeto y su manejo

Tengo este ejemplo que espero se entienda y puedan ayudarme porque no encuentro una referencia que me ayude.

¿Al poner `plantillaEmpleado = []` está mal? Estaría definiéndolo como una variable global.
¿Debo crear otra clase pej, `Empresa` donde este el constructor `__init__(self, objEmpleados, nombreEmpresa)`, por ejemplo?
¿y pongo if xxx **main** etc etc.?
¿O creo un método `def plantillaEmpleado(self, objEmpleado)` que vaya agregando los empleados que se van creando?

Si en la class Principal de Main.py estoy creando el objeto empleado, no entiendo por qué puedo NO usar la clase `Trabajador` de **Empleado.py**? Y funciona igual.

**Main.py**

```py
plantillaEmpleados = []
class Principal:

  def cargarEmpleado():
    numID = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO IDENTIFICADOR DEL EMPLEADO.\n'))
    while(numID != 0):
      nombre = input('INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO. \n')
      apellido = input('INGRESE EL APELLIDO. \n')
      sueldo = float(input('INGRESE EL SUELDO. \n'))
      objEmpleado = [numID, nombre, apellido, sueldo]
      plantillaEmpleados.append(objEmpleado)
      numID = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO IDENTIFICADOR DEL EMPLEADO.\n'))
  
  def muestraEmpleados():
      print ('LOS EMPLEADOS CARGADOS SON: \n', plantillaEmpleados)

while True:
  print('*****************************************************************\n')
  print ('1_ CARGA EMPLEADO.')
  print ('2_ muestra empleados cargados \n')
  opcion = int(input('INGRESE UNA OPCION \n'))
  if opcion == 1:
    cargarEmpleado()

  if opcion == 2:
    muestraEmpleados()

  if opcion == 0:
    exit()
```

**Empleado.py**

```py
class Trabajador:
  def Empleado(self, id, nombre, apellido, sueldo):
    '''Definicion de un empleado.'''
    self.apellido = apellido
    self.id = id
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.sueldo = sueldo
```

Comment: NO GRITES, que no es necesario ;)

Comment: por el 'NO'.?  ahi lo vi.  se me colo cuando lo pase del borrador pa'ca...  Perdon, Perdon.

Comment: Realmente era por el título en mayúscula sostenida. Gracias por mejorar la pregunta :)

Answer (score 1):

Así como lo planteas puede ser tomado como una pregunta basada en opiniones. Pero bueno, es usual, mas no obligatorio que una clase tenga un método `__init__()`
¿Qué va en ese método?. Parámetros, que según el desarrollador, deben iniciar la clase.

Posiblemente tu programa no es el mejor para ilustrar esto ya que empieza de una lista vacía de empleados. Sin embargo, posibles valores para pasar en `__init__` podrían ser generalidades de la empresa: El nombre, la dirección y el contacto de la misma.

Voy a reescribir tu código de manera que funcione, hice algunos cambios en los nombres de las clases. El atributo `plantillaEmpleados` le pertenece a la clase padre, ya que es un contenedor de todos los empleados.
Para poder comunicar a la clase padre con su hija, lo más usual es por [herencia](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+herencia).

Adicional se puede hacer uso del método `__init__` del padre desde la clase hija, para lo cual usé la función especial [super()](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+super), aunque se puede hacer de otras formas. Coloqué variables adicionales `nombre_comp` y `cnombre` para que observes cómo se puede inicializar el constructor de la clase padre desde la hija.

```py
class Planilla: # <- Clase padre
    def __init__(self, cnombre):
        self.plantillaEmpleados = []
        self.cnombre = cnombre
        
    def muestraEmpleados(self):
        print (f'LOS EMPLEADOS CARGADOS DE {self.cnombre} SON: {self.plantillaEmpleados}\n')

class Trabajador(Planilla): # <- Clase hija
    def __init__(self, nombre_comp):
        super().__init__(nombre_comp) # Usar el constructor del padre
        
    def cargarEmpleado(self):
        while(True):
            numID = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO IDENTIFICADOR DEL EMPLEADO.\n'))
            if numID <= 0:
                print('El ID no puede ser 0, ni negativo')
                continue
            nombre = input('INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO. \n')
            apellido = input('INGRESE EL APELLIDO. \n')
            sueldo = float(input('INGRESE EL SUELDO. \n'))
            objEmpleado = [numID, nombre, apellido, sueldo]
            self.plantillaEmpleados.append(objEmpleado)
            break

obj = Trabajador('EMPRESA XYZ') # <-- Crear una instancia para llamar a los métodos
while True:
    print('*****************************************************************\n')
    print ('1_ CARGA EMPLEADO.')
    print ('2_ muestra empleados cargados \n')
    opcion = int(input('INGRESE UNA OPCION \n'))
    if opcion == 1:
        obj.cargarEmpleado()
    if opcion == 2:
        obj.muestraEmpleados()
    if opcion == 0:
        break
```

Comment: Gracias, por la respuesta.  Esto es muy de universidad.  Un error que genera otra equivocaci'on.  Estudiando.

Comment: Antes que nada, s'e que respondieron y lo agradezco.  Me preocupa mucho que no me ande el c'odigo.  Lo que detecte es que plantillaEmpleados no est[a definida en Main.py y si lo est[a en Empleado.py .  ahora cuando importo, no lo toma y cuando busco el origen obviamente no est[a definido.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas lo primera aclaración:
-No existe algo como globales o privacidad en python las variables y métodos se pueden acceder a través de otros como las clases o por indentación.
-El **__init__** es el constructor de cada clase, si no tiene constructor no se puede inicializar, por ejemplo la clase main no tiene y puedes usar las funciones iguales.

La ventaja de los **__init__** respecto a las funciones es en las herencias de clase y que las propiedades se guardan, por lo que te recomiendo que cuando tengas una clase al insertar campos metas
el constructor en vez de una función.

Errores o Cosas que faltan:

-Para importar un código desde un fichero en el mismo directorio:

```
import Empleado.py#importar fitchero empleado.py
```

-Cuando asignabas objempleado como lista [] de los parametros lo añadias en la lista haciendo un lista de listas [[],[]]. He inicializado la clase Trabajador con los parámetros en el objempleado:

```
  objEmpleado =  Trabajador(numID, nombre, apellido, sueldo) #definicion de un empleado
```

-Para llamar una función de una clase no inicializada como Principal tienes que usar:

```
Principal.cargarEmpleado()#recordar que no se guardan los parametros de dentro las funciones
```

Mala praxis y cosas necessarias:
-While true y usar exit() es mala praxis mejor hacer una variable booleana y assignar a false para que salga del bucle cuando se quiera
-Para poder imprimir los campos de una classe propia hace falta que sobrescribas el **str**:

```
def __str__(self): #Ajustamos el string de la forma que queremos valor Base la referencia
return f'Empleado(id={self.id},nombre={self.nombre},apellido={self.apellido},sueldo={self.sueldo})'
```

Código Completo arreglado:

Empleado.py

```
class Trabajador:
def __init__(self, id, nombre, apellido, sueldo):# definicion de empleado puede haber mas __init__ #es el contructor de la classe
    '''Definicion de un empleado.'''
    self.apellido = apellido
    self.id = id
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.sueldo = sueldo
def __str__(self): #Ajustamos el string de la forma que queremos valor Base la referencia
    return f'Empleado(id={self.id},nombre={self.nombre},apellido={self.apellido},sueldo={self.sueldo})'
plantillaEmpleados = []
```

Main.py

```
#from Pathquesea import Empleado.py#importar fitchero empleado.py
class Principal:#no hace falta ya que no guardas ninguna propiedad solo usas funciones

 def cargarEmpleado():
    numID = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO IDENTIFICADOR DEL EMPLEADO.\n'))
    while(numID != 0):
    nombre = input('INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO. \n')
    apellido = input('INGRESE EL APELLIDO. \n')
    sueldo = float(input('INGRESE EL SUELDO. \n'))
    objEmpleado =  Trabajador(numID, nombre, apellido, sueldo) #definicion de un empleado
    plantillaEmpleados.append(objEmpleado)#lo añadimos a la lista
    numID = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO IDENTIFICADOR DEL EMPLEADO.\n'))

 def muestraEmpleados():
    print ('LOS EMPLEADOS CARGADOS SON: ')#no hace falta barra \n ya viene por defecto
    for a in plantillaEmpleados:
        print(' ',a)

Vueltas=True 
while  Vueltas:  #True:#mala praxis
    print('*****************************************************************\n')#no cabe con indentación
   #culpable del mal formateo
    print ('1_ CARGA EMPLEADO.')
    print ('2_ muestra empleados cargados \n')
    opcion = int(input('INGRESE UNA OPCION \n'))
    if opcion == 1:
        Principal.cargarEmpleado()

    if opcion == 2:
        Principal.muestraEmpleados()

    if opcion == 0:
        Vueltas=False
```

Output del muestraEmpleados():

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, por la respuesta.  Esto es muy de universidad.  Un error que genera otra equivocaci'on.  Estudiando.

Comment: Un comentario. Entendi tu respuesta @rexxarcat . Cuando ejecuto el codigo, no hace nada!. Nunca ejecuta el m'etodo cargaEmpleado, muestraEmpleado. Hay algo que estoy omitiendo? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puede ser que no hayas importado el  empleado.py? te lo deje comentado ya que no se donde lo ubicas. A parte de eso el codigo es exactament igual al de la prueba que mostre en el resultado

Comment: Ya veo el problema se ha formateado mal la indentación dentro del while por culpa de que el print es demasiado largo. Por eso no se ejecuta si lo has copiado y pegado. Arreglado

Comment: .nou @rexxarcat. me d'i cuenta de  todo lo que comentas. importo bien, y arregle la identaci'on pero no. no quiere.  me fijo que puede ser.  ya me pico... gracias, por tu respuesta. cuidate.  de hecho, algo que vi es que uso from Empleado import * si pongo from Empleado import Trabajado la lista plantillaEmpleados en la class Principal me da error(no est[a definida.).  raro!

Comment: Si muy raro actualiza el código a ver si hay algo que falta

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, s'e que respondieron y lo agradezco.  Me preocupa mucho que no me ande el c'odigo porque no entiendo como plantillaEmpleados no est'a definida y funcionaria.  Porbe muchas cosas diferentes y sigue sin funcionar. Me preocupa meter la pata y generar un error y no darme cuenta luego.  Lo que detecte es que plantillaEmpleados no est[a definida en Main.py y si lo est[a en Empleado.py. Y est'a definida fuera de los metodos de la clase.  ahora cuando importo, no lo toma y cuando busco el origen obviamente no est[a definido.
No tiene ni herencia este codigo.

A todo lo anterior, comento que simplifique un poquito el c'odigo.  Basicamente, no estoy logrando acceder al m'etodo **str**() en la clase Trabajador.  Me preocupa muchisimo porque no s'e qu'e estoy haciendo mal.
Main.py

```
from Empleado import *

class Principal:
  def cargarEmpleado():
    numID = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO ID DEL EMPLEADO.\n'))
    while(numID != 0):
      nombre = input('INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO. \n')
      objEmpleado =  Trabajador(numID, nombre) 
      plantillaEmpleados.append(objEmpleado)
      numID = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO ID DEL EMPLEADO.\n'))
 
  def muestraEmpleados():
    for a in plantillaEmpleados:
      print('DATOS: ', a.__str__())

Vueltas=True # fix!!
plantillaEmpleados = []
while  Vueltas: 
  print('**********************************\n')
  print ('1_ CARGAR EMPLEADOS.')
  print ('2_ MOSTRAR EMPLEADOS.')
  opcion = int(input('INGRESE UNA OPCION\n'))
  if opcion == 1:
     Principal.cargarEmpleado()
  if opcion == 2:
     Principal.muestraEmpleados()
  if opcion == 0:
     Vueltas=False
```

Empleado.py

```
class Trabajador:
  def __init__(self, id, nombre):
    self.id = id
    self.nombre = nombre

  def __str__(self):
     '''Muestra empleado.'''
     return f'Empleado(id={self.id},nombre={self.nombre})'
```

EL output luego de la ejecuci'on es:
1_ CARGA EMPLEADO.
2_ MUESTRA EMPLEADOS.
INGRESE UNA OPCION
1
INGRESE EL NUMERO IDENTIFICADOR DEL EMPLEADO.
11
INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO.
DDD
INGRESE EL NUMERO IDENTIFICADOR DEL EMPLEADO.
0

---

1_ CARGA EMPLEADO.
2_ MUESTRA EMPLEADOS.
INGRESE UNA OPCION
2
DATOS:  <Empleado.Trabajador object at 0x000002B88C2DFFD0>

---

1_ CARGA EMPLEADO.
2_ MUESTRA EMPLEADOS.
INGRESE UNA OPCION
0

Ahora, usando F12 en vsc sobre el metodo a.**str**() del en Principal me dice 'no definition found' pero si est'a y no s'e.
Hace tiempo que estoy con esto no logro resolverlo.
Muchas gracias, a quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: plantilla de empleados la tienes fuera de la clase al importar solo tomas la clase `from Empleado import Trabajador`  pd: no tiene mucho sentido meter la lista de empleados en el empleado py lo normal meter la lista en el fichero main.py

Comment: En caso que quieras tenerlo puedes usar `from Empleado import *`  aunque es desaconsejable tambien pudes meter en parentesis lo que quieres añadir `from Empleado import (Trabajador,plantillaEmpleados )` y aqui explican como hacerlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164861/import-de-variables-desde-un-archivo-a-otro-con-el-from

Comment: Est'a mal poner plantillaEmpleados en Trabajador.  La definici'on de un empleado no incluye la lista de empleados.  Eso es lo que veo en principio.  Entonces, es aca cuando llego hasta ac'a, hice una consulta, me respondieron diciendo que hicieron correcciones y me muestran que funciona y hasta donde veo, la cosa no va.  Gracias, por el tiempo prestado.  Veo como sigo y si, seguire preguntando.  Salutis.

Comment: Resuelto.  Gracias, a todos. Sigo.